# Connecting AWS Domain name to github pages

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, jekyll

I can not connect my Jekyll site hosted on GitHub pages to my domain name with AWS E2. If someone has step by step instructions or could point me in the right direction that would be amazing.

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by AWS domain. That means, your Domain's DNS is with AWS Route 53?

Answer (score 0):

In your domain's DNS, just create a CNAME record and point that to  YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME.github.io.

You can verify your domain's CNAME record with `dig` command. For details, github has an article about that [custom domain name setup for GitHub pages](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-subdomain/)